How to get t.me link from rbmy telegram mini app. And how to get user details on miniapp
I am a beginner, i t to know how to get t.me link for telegram webapp. Example: https://t.me/botusername/webApp
And how to get user details on WebApp. I want a sample code snippet to learn, bot shows user details on web page. example: hellob {user.first_name} and user.telegramif etc..
I want some code snippet, i want bot script in php and web script in html/js/css
